# how to inject into a bean the values of a properties file read from controller?

Tags: java, spring, properties, dependency-injection

I want to read properties from a .properties file using a controller and display its value in jsp file, which is a view using dependency injection, by storing the retrieved properties in a pojo.

Comment: Please try to submit a little so that it can help to dig in your issue

Comment: Why would you store the values in POJO, I think it's rather about MessageSource org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource - following is the first link google suggests : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) for this. The properties will be loaded by spring so no need for your controller to do this. You can inject the properties directly into your view.

Comment: hi, this might be stupid question but i don't know the answer.. If spring loads a Properties file through PropertyPlaceholder, how can i access it in my jsp(view)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Component
class MyComponent {

  @Property(key = "proo.xmlurl")
  public void setUrlString(String urlStr) {
        try {
            this.url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(urlStr + " is not a valid http         url", e);
        }
    }
}
```

in your properties files put this

```
proo.xmlurl=${proo.xmlurl}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppContext can have this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Controller can have this

```
@Value("${language}")
private String language;

@Value("${allLanguages}")
private String allLanguages;
```

where properties file contains this, or similar

```
language = java 
alllanguages = java and \
               c++
somethingelse = whatever
```